# get image width and height from webClient response

Tags: c#, webrequest

I want to get image sizes (width and height)

[image: Example logo]

```
var source = "http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenRead(source);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(source);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Image image = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
```